# Updating multiple android device OS with a script or a shell command

Tags: android, enterprise, automatic-updates

I am working on a project that we use internally in the company. We have a single target device and at this time and that is the Google Nexus 7.

1. I need to find the quickest and least painful way to update the
   android OS on every one of them (we are talking about a couple of
   hundred of devices).
2. I am also looking for suggestions on how to distribute the app
   version and updates afterwards. Updates are not something i want to
   do through my app, that is implementing some code that will check
   and download updates.

I already tried TestFlight which i feel takes too long to setup on each device,
Also tried Deploying through the Google Play beta program but the updates take too much time to show up, plus the setup is kinda wierd (i feel this is the best way to do it). i know of the google play enterprise apps distribution, but i need to have a google account linked to google apps and a developer account so i haven't tried that still.
I also was looking into https://www.push-link.com/ which seems interesting. Any alternative?

Any suggestions are really appreciated!
Thanks